# In hotel lifts requiring swipe card access, is it normal to swipe or press the floor button first?

Tags: buttons, physical

Having been overseas to a number of different countries recently, I noticed that there doesn't seem to be any convention when it comes to the way people are meant to use the hotel lifts. Some guests will try to press the floor button and then swipe their card, but some people will do the opposite. In some lifts the order doesn't matter, but even in those that do, there is no clear indication what the order is supposed to be.

Just wondering if anyone has seen any conventions around this, or even lifts that provide instructions. I guess if people try one way and it doesn't work then they will probably try the other.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any conventions around this, but I have always swiped, then hit the floor button, in that order.

Comment: And your experience would be in which countries?

Comment: A bit more information would be useful. Right now it reads as a comment instead of an answer!

Comment: @michael-lai this would be specifically U.S., Japan, S.Korea, U.K., higher-end hotels, office buildings (U.S.)